# How to return a value inside a builder? [Flutter]

Tags: datetime, flutter

My application has a `PageView.builder` which displays pages based on dates(ex: initial page will be set to `DateTime.now()`) and when the user swipes left or right, it will change the page and the displayed date accordingly.

I also have a calendar and i want it to let the user jump to a page which they select in the calendar. The selected date is present inside a `builder` here :

```
 selectedDayBuilder: (context, date, _) { //need to return date
//          var value = MonthPageViewExample(date);
          return FadeTransition(
            opacity: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_animationController),
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, left: 6.0),
              color: Colors.deepOrange[300],
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              child: Text(
                  '${date.day}',
                  style: TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 16.0),
                ),
                ),
          );
        },
```

I want to use the date as a parameter which will be passed on the `PageView.builder` and then the page with the selected date will be displayed on the screen.

Could i get some suggestion on how i can store the date value inside a parameter (perhaps) so that i can pass it to the `PageView.builder`?

Also I have tried to find tutorials on how to return a value inside a builder method in general but i had no luck with it. It would also help if this method could be used for returning a value from any type of builder method

Comment: Don’t get your code completely but i would create my calendar pages inside PageView.builder and then control which Page is displayed by attaching a PageController and use jumpToPage() see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController-class.html

Comment: unfortunately i cannot create the calendar inside my ```PageView.builder``` file because in this application, the user will be able to see the ```PageView.builder``` page initially and then they should be able to navigate to another page which has the calendar widget defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a temporary workaround for this question by using a Global variable. I have defined the variable as `DateTime universal = DateTime.now()`. I passed this variable inside the `selectedDayBuilder` this way:

```
   selectedDayBuilder: (context, date, _) {
          Calendar_screen(dateToString(date));
          universal = date;   // Selected date is assigned the user selected value here
          return FadeTransition(
            opacity: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_animationController),
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, left: 6.0),
              color: Colors.deepOrange[300],
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onDoubleTap: () async{
                  final PageRouteBuilder _route = PageRouteBuilder(
                      pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
                    return DayPageViewExample(date);
                  });
                  await Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, _route, (Route<dynamic> r) => false);
                },
                child: Text(
                    '${date.day}',
                    style: TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 16.0),
                  ),
              ),
                ),
          );
        },
```

I am able to pass the `DateTime universal` to any other widget present in this screen and it successfully passes the date selected inside the `selectedDayBuilder`.

Comment: If someone can specify any other method aside from using a Global variable please feel free to share it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "Edit this" ;
Navigator.of(context).push(pageRoute(EditTextPage(text:text))).
        then((result) {
          if(result != null){
            text = result ;
            }
        });
         },

Route pageRoute(Widget page) {
 return PageRouteBuilder(
 pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => page,
transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
  var begin = Offset(0.0, 1.0);
  var end = Offset.zero;
  var curve = Curves.ease;

  var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

  return SlideTransition(
    position: animation.drive(tween),
    child: child,
  );
},
```

);
}